# merge two data set and paste one column

Tags: join, paste

I have two data sets and I need to merge them in a special way below.
My First data set

```
data1=data.frame(store=c(12,13),product=c(1,2))
data1
store product
 12       1
 13       2
data2=data.frame(product=c(1,1,2,2,2),promo=c("promo1","promo2","promo1","promo2","promo3"))
data2
  product  promo
    1    promo1
    1    promo2
    2    promo1
    2    promo2
    2    promo3
```

Desired data set below;

```
  store  product  numberofpromo   promo
   12      1            2         promo1;promo2  
   13      2            3         promo1;promo2;promo3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
               data=data.frame(data2%>%
               group_by(product) %>%
               summarise(promotion=paste(promo,collapse=";"), 
               promo_say=n()))
```

After finding this, you need to the join